# I have to insert a logo in AutoCAD title block by using C#?

Tags: c#, autocad

I have to insert a image in AutoCAD title block at particular insertion point with its width and height, so that I can use scale function to that template while using it. I used RasterImage but not getting the proper result.

please write a code for insert a image at particular point of modelspace in AutoCAD.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I replied to the same question in the Autodesk forum.

```
        static void InsertImage(Database db, string fileName, Point3d position, double width, double height)
    {
        string imgName = System.IO.Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(fileName);
        using (var tr = db.TransactionManager.StartTransaction())
        {
            var imgDictId = RasterImageDef.GetImageDictionary(db);
            if (imgDictId.IsNull)
                imgDictId = RasterImageDef.CreateImageDictionary(db);
            var imgDict = (DBDictionary)tr.GetObject(imgDictId, OpenMode.ForRead);
            ObjectId imgDefId;
            RasterImageDef imgDef;
            if (imgDict.Contains(imgName))
            {
                imgDefId = imgDict.GetAt(imgName);
                imgDef = (RasterImageDef)tr.GetObject(imgDefId, OpenMode.ForRead);
            }
            else
            {
                imgDef = new RasterImageDef();
                imgDef.SourceFileName = fileName;
                imgDef.Load();
                tr.GetObject(imgDictId, OpenMode.ForWrite);
                imgDefId = imgDict.SetAt(imgName, imgDef);
                tr.AddNewlyCreatedDBObject(imgDef, true);
            }

            var modelSpace = (BlockTableRecord)tr.GetObject(
                SymbolUtilityServices.GetBlockModelSpaceId(db), OpenMode.ForWrite);

            var raster = new RasterImage();
            raster.ImageDefId = imgDefId;
            var coordSystem = new CoordinateSystem3d(
                position, Vector3d.XAxis * width, Vector3d.YAxis * height);
            raster.Orientation = coordSystem;
            modelSpace.AppendEntity(raster);
            tr.AddNewlyCreatedDBObject(raster, true);
            RasterImage.EnableReactors(true);
            raster.AssociateRasterDef(imgDef);
            tr.Commit();
        }
    }
```