# Use C# to pull image from URL store it in AutoCAD DWG file without xref

Tags: c#, image, autocad

I have seen the post here:
[I have to insert a logo in AutoCAD title block by using C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73659496/i-have-to-insert-a-logo-in-autocad-title-block-by-using-c?newreg=f4361c319f0a4b31ac7708914c15c71b)

And my question is related to that.

Can anyone show me the same thing, only doing it without a file. I have a URL that contains an image. I want to pull the contents of the URL (byte array/stream/whatever) and use that to store the image in the dwg file permanently, rather than xfref'ing a file.

Help greatly appreciated!

I've tried several things but can't figure out how to get around the file problem.